# vba to copy data and rearrange data from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to this forum, and in need of some help with getting information from a budget spreadsheet to a workbook. The spreadsheet I'm pulling from has data spread out in multiple columns and rows, and there are many blank cells, but I need it to be laid out in a line-item format in the workbook with no blanks.
I'm able to manually link each cell and row in each sheet, but it requires a lot of code and isn't very elegant. 
I think my best option is to run a loop through Column B, and if there's a value there, then copy all cells with a value in that row to the new sheet.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub ImportBudget_Click()
Dim BudgetBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim BudgetFileName As String
Dim ActiveBook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the budget workbook
 filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
 caption = "Please Select an input file "
 BudgetFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

 Set BudgetBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(BudgetFileName)

 ' copy data from budget to target workbook
 Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
 Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
 Set sourceSheet = BudgetBook.Worksheets(1)
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
  j = 2
   For i = 2 To 300
    If sourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" And sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
    targetSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    targetSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
    targetSheet.Cells(j, 3).Value = sourceSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value
     j = j + 1

   End If
  Next i

 BudgetBook.Close
End Sub
```

The problem with this is that it works well for just one section of the original spreadsheet, however, some areas have up to 9 columns of data in the row. Additionally, because the budget sheet is broken up into different sections, should I rewrite this same code for each section, changing i to the new range?

Comment: You've got decent-enough code here but it's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do. I would say absolutely it is not necessary to "rewrite this same code for each section", but for anyone to offer more guidance, it will be helpful to have a better idea of inputs/outputs, and what you mean by "sections" (i.e., describe how this works for the one section, and how doesn't it work for other section(s)?)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm working with some pretty sensitive information, otherwise I would have posted the source sheet. By sections, I mean that the budget sheet is broken out into multiple expense types, each of which carries its own set of data and is even organized differently from section to section. The reason the original code worked for one section is that the data there is fixed and always filled in, however, other sections require more detail and don't always get filled...

Comment: Sanitize the data, then, present a worksheet with dummy data. The actual data doesn't matter, but it is important for anyone trying to help you to have a good understanding of what you're working with and what you're trying to accomplish. And also, add your clarifying remarks to the body of the question itself ([by editing it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38961626/edit)) not the comments:

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through `sourceSheet` and any row between 2 and 300 that has a value in column A or B (1 or 2) it will take and loop through all columns between 1 and the last column with data. Then, all non-blank cells within that column range, and in that row, will be put into `targetSheet` in a new row with no spaces between the data in the columns.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub ImportBudget_Click()
Dim BudgetBook As Workbook
Dim filter As String
Dim caption As String
Dim BudgetFileName As String
Dim ActiveBook As Workbook
Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
Dim i as Single, k as Single, counter as Single

Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

' get the budget workbook
 filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx"
 caption = "Please Select an input file "
 BudgetFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)

 Set BudgetBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(BudgetFileName)

 ' copy data from budget to target workbook
 Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
 Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
 Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
 Set sourceSheet = BudgetBook.Worksheets(1)

 j = 2

 With sourceSheet
   For i = 2 To 300
    If .Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" And .Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then

       counter = 1

       For k = 1 to .Cells(i,.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
          If .Cells(i,k) <> "" Then
             targetSheet.Cells(j,counter) = .Cells(i,k)
             counter = counter + 1
          End if
       Next k
     j = j + 1

   End If
  Next i
 End With

 BudgetBook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! This gets me much closer to what I'm trying to accomplish. I'll need to modify for some specific needs, but thank you very much for sharing this!! Will update the code above later on when I get this worked out!!

Comment: Let me know if you run into any other issues and I'd be glad to help you work through them. Please mark as answered if you feel this sufficiently answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to skip the blank rows, then something like this

```
Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

Set sourceRange = Intersect(sourceRange.EntireRow, sourceRange.EntireColumn)

sourceRange.Copy

targetSheet.Paste
```

If you have formulas or anything else that is not copied, let me know.